# How to use matplotlib to draw axes in groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The data in my csv likes this:

```
staff_id    clock_time  device_id   latitude    longitude
1001    2020/9/20 7:26  d_1 24.48237852 118.1558955
1001    2020/9/20 5:30  d_1 24.59689407 118.0863806
1001    2020/9/18 4:17  d_2 24.59222786 118.0955275
1001    2020/9/16 3:33  d_2 24.59208312 118.0957197
1001    2020/9/15 8:34  d_2 24.59732974 118.0859644
1001    2020/9/14 4:43  d_2 25.68714724 119.3918519
1002    2020/9/13 1:17  d_3 24.58618235 118.1065715
1002    2020/9/11 9:20  d_3 24.63024186 118.0667598
1002    2020/9/10 7:22  d_3 24.48287497 118.1542957
1002    2020/9/7 5:38   d_4 25.07601853 118.7335211
1003    2020/9/5 5:44   d_6 24.59803941 118.0863071
1003    2020/9/4 7:37   d_6 24.48285023 118.1545752
1003    2020/9/3 2:38   d_6 24.6381382  118.0677933
1003    2020/8/31 6:43  d_7 24.49278011 118.1395677
1003    2020/8/30 11:41 d_7 24.59205252 118.0955596
1003    2020/8/29 3:35  d_7 24.51817637 118.1764342
1003    2020/8/28 5:05  d_7 24.59603175 118.0846872
1003    2020/8/27 2:55  d_8 26.39899424 117.7866387
1003    2020/8/26 7:45  d_8 26.39900029 117.7866379
1003    2020/8/26 3:09  d_8 26.40672436 117.8008659
1003    2020/8/26 0:26  d_8 26.89169118 117.1612365
1003    2020/8/25 9:38  d_8 26.89764297 117.1760012
1003    2020/5/19 8:29  d_8 24.47420087 118.1085551
1003    2020/5/18 9:06  d_8 24.473124   118.1705641
1003    2020/5/16 7:54  d_8 24.5101858  117.8954614
```

I want to group by `staff_id` and `device_id`, and then use matplotlib to draw each person's trajectory coordinates, which is a scatter plot of `latitude` and `longitude`, from old time to new time according to `clock_time`.
How to do it?

For matplotlib, the only code I can write is these:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'for_test.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
x = df['latitude']
y = df['longitude']
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

But there is no grouping according to staff_id and device_id, and no scatter plot of latitude and longitude according to time series. I want to group according to staff_id and device_id, and draw a picture for each group.

Comment: Please format your data properly. Something's not right.

Comment: I have formatted my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It groups the data and draws a scatter plot for each group from the resulting group objects in a loop process. Prepare the same color and marker type as the number of groups.

```
gb = df.groupby(['staff_id','device_id'])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
color = ['r','b','g','k','m','y','pink']
marker = ['o','8','s','p','*','h','D']
for c,m, (name, group) in zip(color,marker,gb):
    gp = group
    ax.scatter(gp.latitude, gp.longitude, color=c, s=100, marker=m, label=name)
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks！If I want to draw a picture in a group, what should I do, I want the same `staff_id` and `device_id` are displayed on a picture separately.Then loop all groups.

Comment: The technique is basically the same, for example, the first loop can be handled by drawing the ID in green and the second loop by drawing the device in red.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. At beginning i made some modifications to load properly the data from string. You can read the code starting from the loop.

```
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = StringIO("""
1001    2020/9/20 7:26  d_1 24.48237852 118.1558955
1001    2020/9/20 5:30  d_1 24.59689407 118.0863806
1001    2020/9/18 4:17  d_2 24.59222786 118.0955275
1001    2020/9/16 3:33  d_2 24.59208312 118.0957197
1001    2020/9/15 8:34  d_2 24.59732974 118.0859644
1001    2020/9/14 4:43  d_2 25.68714724 119.3918519
1002    2020/9/13 1:17  d_3 24.58618235 118.1065715
1002    2020/9/11 9:20  d_3 24.63024186 118.0667598
1002    2020/9/10 7:22  d_3 24.48287497 118.1542957
1002    2020/9/7 5:38   d_4 25.07601853 118.7335211
1003    2020/9/5 5:44   d_6 24.59803941 118.0863071
1003    2020/9/4 7:37   d_6 24.48285023 118.1545752
1003    2020/9/3 2:38   d_6 24.6381382  118.0677933
1003    2020/8/31 6:43  d_7 24.49278011 118.1395677
1003    2020/8/30 11:41 d_7 24.59205252 118.0955596
1003    2020/8/29 3:35  d_7 24.51817637 118.1764342
1003    2020/8/28 5:05  d_7 24.59603175 118.0846872
1003    2020/8/27 2:55  d_8 26.39899424 117.7866387
1003    2020/8/26 7:45  d_8 26.39900029 117.7866379
1003    2020/8/26 3:09  d_8 26.40672436 117.8008659
1003    2020/8/26 0:26  d_8 26.89169118 117.1612365
1003    2020/8/25 9:38  d_8 26.89764297 117.1760012
1003    2020/5/19 8:29  d_8 24.47420087 118.1085551
1003    2020/5/18 9:06  d_8 24.473124   118.1705641
1003    2020/5/16 7:54  d_8 24.5101858  117.8954614
""")


df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True, names=['staff_id', 'date', 'time', 'device_id', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
df = df.drop(['date', 'time'], axis=1)
grouped_data = df.groupby(['staff_id', 'device_id'])

for group_name, grouped_df in grouped_data:
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    x = df['date_time']
    y1 = df['latitude']
    y2 = df['longitude']
    ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g.')
    ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b.')
    ax1.set_ylabel('latitude', color='g')
    ax2.set_ylabel('longitude', color='b')
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.title('ID = ' + str(grouped_df['staff_id'].values[0]) + '/' + str(grouped_df['device_id'].values[0]))
    plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi,if clock_time is the x-axis, then the longitude is gone.I feel that this requires a 3-dimensional space to achieve it.The 3 dimensional space is clock_time, longitude, latitude.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fillter_data = df.groupby(['staff_id','device_id'])
for staff_id,saff_df in fillter_data:
 
    plt.plot(df['longitude'],df['latitude'], '*')
    plt.title('ID = ' + str(staff_id[0]) +'Device = ' + str(staff_id[1]))
    plt.show()
```